# ¿Cómo hacer un procedimiento o función que devuelva los registros de una tabla en oracle?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

al usar SQL server, sé que solamente tendría que colocar dentro del procedimiento un select para devolver todos los registros de la tabla, pero ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso en oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma, donde aparece el SELECT solo llama a los campos que quieras:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "SP_LISTAR_CLIENTE" (v_cliente out SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN   
    OPEN v_cliente FOR SELECT * FROM TU_TABLA;
END SP_LISTAR_CLIENTE;
```